# Upload rich text editor result to windows azure

Tags: azure, upload, ftp

How can I upload html content to website - I need to specifye internet address in my desctop client and I dont know what address should I type - this

```
    publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod-am2-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot
```

or something else.How can I list site content? Is there any microsoft text editor exist - than it will be easier to publish using publish profile.

Answer (score 1):

Now sure what desktop client you are using. Based on your above info it seems you are using Windows Azure Websites so I will give you simple idea to upload HTML content from FTP client.

What you really need is install a FTP client in your desktop (i.e. FileZilla) and then setup your Azure Website FTP location.

Please follow my blog below to setup your FileZilla FTP client first:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx

Once your FTP client is configured and you can see the Website folder you can just drag and drop HTML files from local machine to Windows Azure Websites.